# Cannot find symbol - variable java

Tags: java

I am trying to do the following program in `Java` where I'm writing a recursive and an iterative method to compute the sum of all odd numbers from `n` to `m`

> import java.util.Scanner;
>
> public class AssignmentQ7 {
>
> ```
> public static int recursivesum(int n, int m){
>
>     if (n < m){
>         int s = n;
>         s += recursivesum(n+2, m);
>
>     } else{
>         if(m < n){
>             int  s = m;
>             s += recursivesum(m+2, n);
>
>         }
>     }
>     return s;
> }
>
> public static int iterativesum(int n, int m){
>     if(n < m){
>         int s = n;
>         for(int i = n; i <= m; i += 2){
>             s += i; 
>                     return s;
>         }
>     } else
>         if(m < n){
>             int s = m;
>             for(int i = m; i <= n; i += 2){
>             s += i; 
>                     return s;
>             }
>         }
>
> }
>
> public static void main(String args[]){
>
>     int n,m;
>
>     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
>
>     System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");
>     n = in.nextInt();
>     m = in.nextInt();
>
>     while(n%2 == 0){
>         System.out.println("Enter the first number again: ");
>         n = in.nextInt();
>     }
>
>     while(m%2 == 0){
>         System.out.println("Enter the second number again: ");
>         m = in.nextInt();
>     }
>
>     System.out.println("The answer of the recursive sum is: " + recursivesum(n,m));
>     System.out.println("The answer of the iterative sum is: " + iterativesum(n,m));
> }
>  }
> ```

I'm getting an error cannot find symbol - variable `enter code here`s. I don't know what's wrong! Can anyone help please?

Comment: scope of s is with in the braces...define it outside as class variable

Comment: @VinayVeluri: There's no need for it to be a class variable.

Comment: declare your s variable outside your if condition

Comment: @JonSkeet true!! any variable whose scope doesn't end before return.

Answer (score 5):

This method is the problem:

```
public static int recursivesum(int n, int m) {
    if (n < m) {
        int s = n; // Variable declared here... scoped to the if
        s += recursivesum(n+2, m);

    } else {
        if (m < n) {
            int  s = m; // Variable declared here... scoped to this if
            s += recursivesum(m+2, n);
        }
    }
    return s; // No such variable in scope!
}
```

You could use:

```
public static int recursivesum(int n, int m) {
    int s = 0; // See note below
    if (n < m) {
        s = n + recursivesum(n+2, m);

    } else {
        if (m < n) {
            s = m + recursivesum(m+2, n);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

We have to give `s` an explicit initial value, because you currently don't have any code handling the case where `n` and `m` are equal. It's not clear what you want to do then.

Another alternative is to return from the `if` statements, just as you do in `iterativesum`... although you'll again need to think about what to do if `m == n`:

```
public static int recursivesum(int n, int m) {
    if (n < m) {
        // You don't even need an s variable!
        return n + recursivesum(n+2, m);   
    } else if (m < n) {
        // Simplified else { if { ... } } to else if { .... }
        return m + recursivesum(m+2, n);
    } else {
        // What do you want to return here?
    }
}
```

Note that you've got the same problem in `iterativesum` - the compiler should be complaining at you at the moment that not all paths return a value. What do you expect `iterativesum(3, 3)` to do?

Answer (score 2):

in `recursivesum(int n, int m)` method, you have declared `s` within if condition, but, you tried to access it in else part.

```
public static int recursivesum(int n, int m){
    int s = n; // Now s having method local scope

    if (n < m){
        s += recursivesum(n+2, m);

    } else{
        if(m < n){
            int  s = m;
            s += recursivesum(m+2, n);

        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `recursivesum(int n,int m)` function the scope of `variable s` is inside the `if and else` block. When your returning `s` it is out of scope.

Try using some IDE's like `eclipse`. So that you can debug these errors instantly

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int s;
if (n < m){
        s = n;
        s += recursivesum(n+2, m);

    } else{
        if(m < n){
            int  s = m;
            s += recursivesum(m+2, n);

        }
    }
    return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring variable `s` inside `if` statement, that is why you get such error. Start from declaration `int s` outside `if` statement.

Answer (score 0):

your `s` is out of scope in `recursivesum(int n, int m)` method

Answer (score 0):

Declare `s` outside the `if-else` block

Answer (score 0):

It's scope problem. You're declaring variable s inside the if statements which is (local definition) of variable.

You need to modify the two methods as follows:

The recursive method will be

```
public static int recursivesum(int n, int m) {
    int s = 0;
    if (n < m) {
        s = n;
        s += recursivesum(n + 2, m);
    } else {
        if(m < n){
            s = m;
            s += recursivesum(m + 2, n);
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

And the iterative method will be:

```
public static int iterativesum(int n, int m) {
    int s = 0;
    if(n < m) {
        s = n;
        for(int i = n; i <= m; i += 2) {
            s += i;
        }
    } else {
        if(m < n) {
            s = m;
            for(int i = m; i <= n; i += 2) {
                s += i;
            }
        }
     }
     return s;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the first method where you define `s` outside the scope which you return it from. In the second method you return inside the loop.

As others in this thread suggests, use an IDE like Eclipse (https://www.eclipse.org/) or IntelliJ (http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignmentQ7  {

  public static int recursivesum(int n, int m) {
    int s = n;
    if (n < m) {
      s += recursivesum(n + 2, m);
    }
    else {
      if (m < n) {
        s = m;
        s += recursivesum(m + 2, n);
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  public static int iterativesum(int n, int m) {
    int s = 0;
    if (n < m) {
      for (int i = n; i <= m; i += 2) {
        s += i;
      }
    }
    else if (m < n) {
      for (int i = m; i <= n; i += 2) {
        s += i;
      }
    }
    return s;
  }

  public static void main(String args[]) {

    int n, m;

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");
    n = in.nextInt();
    m = in.nextInt();

    while (n % 2 == 0) {
      System.out.println("Enter the first number again: ");
      n = in.nextInt();
    }

    while (m % 2 == 0) {
      System.out.println("Enter the second number again: ");
      m = in.nextInt();
    }

    System.out.println("The answer of the recursive sum is: " + recursivesum(n, m));
    System.out.println("The answer of the iterative sum is: " + iterativesum(n, m));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code must be like this, you dont have to use two `for loop`.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AssignmentQ7 {

    public static int recursivesum(final int n, final int m) {

        final int lower = n < m ? n : m;
        final int upper = n > m ? n : m;
        final int total = lower;

        if (lower >= upper) {
            return total;
        }
        return total + AssignmentQ7.recursivesum(lower + 2, upper);
    }

    public static int iterativesum(final int n, final int m) {

        final int lower = n < m ? n : m;
        final int upper = n > m ? n : m;

        int total = 0;
        for (int num = lower; num <= upper; num = num + 2) {
            total += num;
        }

        return total;
    }

    public static void main(final String args[]) {

        int n, m;

        final Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");
        n = in.nextInt();
        m = in.nextInt();

        while (n % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter the first number again: ");
            n = in.nextInt();
        }

        while (m % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter the second number again: ");
            m = in.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println("The answer of the recursive sum is: " + AssignmentQ7.recursivesum(n, m));
        System.out.println("The answer of the iterative sum is: " + AssignmentQ7.iterativesum(n, m));
    }
}
```